# MarkdownSharp does not transform list

Tags: c#, markdown, markdownsharp

The following string will properly be transformed from a markdown list to an HTML list:

`string list = "* Item1\n* Item 2";`

However, if I have some other string, then append the list to it, the output is unexpected.

`string text = "here is some **bold** text " + list;`

output:

`here is some <b>bold</b> text * Item1 * Item 2`

It seems the problem is trying to transform a list that exists in a block of other text? If that is the problem, is that the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MarkdownSharp, but most Markdown parsers expect two linebreaks (`\n`) between a paragraph and another paragraph, or new content.

So, by appending the `list`, you remove `Item1` from potentially starting a new list.  By only being a single linebreak (`\n`), MarkdownSharp is most likely not perceiving the content as the start of anything new (just a stray linebreak).

Try concatenating the list with `\n\n`.

```
string text = "here is some **bold** text\n\n" + list;
```

Comment: Shorter answer: yes, that's intended.